# Solving for Euler Angles

Tags: equation-solving, rotation

I would like to determine Euler angles according to the following example.

**My example:**

I have the three vectors in an original set of axes:

```
r1e = {-0.517853, 0., -0.759239}
r2e = {-0.517853, 0., 0.759239}
r3e = {0.0647316, 0., 0.}
```

And after expressing them in a new reference frame they obtain the following components:

```
rt1e={0.310733, -0.358839, -0.786917}
rt2e={0.690333, 0.298661, 0.527983}
rt3e={-0.0625667, 0.00376111, 0.0161833}
```

In reality, I know the Euler angles to be $(30,60,120)$ degrees. How can I get Mathetmatica to give me this?

Comment: Have you tried `EulerAngles`?

Comment: That command won't work, as the rotation matrix itself is not known. Only the two vectors.

Comment: In general, a rotation matrix is _not_ uniquely defined by the action on a single vector...

Comment: Fair enough, but in this case the problem has been constructed such that the three Euler angles are known to exist. The question specifically relates to why NSolve is not working.

Comment: What I tried to say: If you prescribe a pair $u$ and $v$ of same length $\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then there will be a one-parameter family of rotations (and thus a one-parameter family of Euler angles) that map $u$ to $v$. So, it is as it is: Your problem is underdetermined.

Comment: Ah, now, I see it: In `NSolve`, you use `r1te` which is undefined. You have to replace it with `rt1e`. Then `NSolve` will do _something_ but it runs and runs and does not return anything. Probably because `NSolve` assumes that the equation is sufficiently nondegenareate so that Newton's method can be applied. But this assumptions is violated here because there is a one-parameter family of solutions, something, that an unprepared Newton method is not able to cope with.

Comment: Please see edits to the problem statement. I actually have 3 vectors available and want to determine the Euler angles defining the change of coordinate frame between them.

Comment: "I actually have 3 vectors" - by this, do you mean the three vectors before and after being transformed by some rotation matrix? If so, please look at `FindGeometricTransform[]`, which can be used with `EulerAngles[]`.

Comment: Yes, see the edits added now. Thanks.

Comment: There's a similar problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/217009/the-inverse-problem-of-rotation-of-stress-matrix/218824#218824).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As noted, you can use `FindGeometricTransform[]` in tandem with `EulerAngles[]`:

```
r = {{-0.517853, 0., -0.759239}, {-0.517853, 0., 0.759239}, {0.0647316, 0., 0.}};
rt = {{0.310733, -0.358839, -0.786917}, {0.690333, 0.298661, 0.527983},
      {-0.0625667, 0.00376111, 0.0161833}};

fg = FindGeometricTransform[r, rt];

EulerAngles[Drop[TransformationMatrix[Last[fg]], -1, -1]]/°
   {60.0048, 30.0019, 120.}
```