# The inverse problem of rotation of stress matrix

Tags: rotation

I want to find the degree of rotation between a stress state and the initial stress state.

```
em[α_, β_, γ_] := 
 EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}]\[Transpose].{{10, 0, 
    0}, {0, 20, 0}, {0, 0, 
    25}}.EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}]
res = NMinimize[
  Norm[EulerMatrix[{Pi/2, 0, 0}]\[Transpose].{{10, 0, 0}, {0, 20, 
       0}, {0, 0, 25}}.EulerMatrix[{Pi/2, 0, 0}] - 
    Transpose[em[a, b, c]], "Frobenius"], {a, b, c}, WorkingPrecision->50]
```

I use the above code to get the solution `{a - > 1.16727157, B - > 1.41653756 * 10 ^ - 12, C - > 0.403524756}`. But the error between C which is about 0.4 * 180 and the real rotation angle 0 is large. I want to get `{Pi/2, 0, 0}` or a numerical solution with a small error with `{Pi/2, 0, 0}`. **What shall I do to get a more accurate answer?**

**Response to comments:**

Even if I limit the three variables from - `Pi` to `Pi`, the error of the result (c->-0.221782576) is still large. I feel that the norm selection is not accurate, but I don't know how to further improve this code to get more accurate results ( I want to get `{Pi/2, 0, 0}` or a numerical solution with a small error with `{Pi/2, 0, 0}`).

```
em[α_, β_, γ_] := 
 EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}]\[Transpose].{{10, 0, 
    0}, {0, 20, 0}, {0, 0, 
    25}}.EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}]
res = NMinimize[{Norm[
    EulerMatrix[{Pi/2, 0, 0}]\[Transpose].{{10, 0, 0}, {0, 20, 0}, {0,
         0, 25}}.EulerMatrix[{Pi/2, 0, 0}] - Transpose[em[a, b, c]], 
    "Frobenius"], (0 <= a <= Pi) && (-Pi <= b <= Pi) && (-Pi <= c <= 
      Pi)}, {a, b, c}]
```

**In other words, I want to use Mathematica to solve the following matrix equation precisely:**

```
A\[Transpose].{{10, 0, 0}, {0, 20, 0}, {0, 0, 25}}.A == {{35/2, (
   5 Sqrt[3])/2, 0}, {(5 Sqrt[3])/2, 25/2, 0}, {0, 0, 25}}
```

The referenced answer of matrix A is `EulerMatrix[{Pi/3, 0, 0}]`.

Comment: If you don't constrain your angles, don't expect a unique solution.

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties I have limited the range of variables, but the error of this result is still large. How can I further modify it?

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties I see you answer a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188949/solving-for-euler-angles) . Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the problem is as follows: Given two symmetric matrices `A` and `B`, find a rotation `R` that minimizes `Norm[A - Transpose[R].B.R]`. It is well-known that such a rotation has to map the principal axes = eigenspaces of `A` onto those of `B`. More precisely, `R` maps the eigenspace of the smallest eigenvalue of `A` onto that one of the smallest eigenvalue of `B` and so on.

Hence, this problem can be solved by using `Eigensystem`.

```
A = #\[Transpose].# &@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}];
R = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[3]];
B = R\[Transpose].A.R;

{λ, U} = Eigensystem[A];
U = Normalize /@ U; (* only necessary for exact and symbolic A*)
{μ, V} = Eigensystem[B];
V = Normalize /@ V; (* only necessary for exact and symbolic B*)
```

Now the rows of `U` and `V` correspond to unit vectors in the eigenspaces. However, each of these unit vectors has two possible directions and it cannot be told a priorily which one is chosen by `Eigensystem`. If the eigenvalues of `A` are pairwise distinct (and thos of `B`, too) `R` must be among one of the rotations in the list `canditates`:

```
signs = Select[Tuples[{1, -1}, 3], Times @@ # == Det[U] &];
canditates = Table[U\[Transpose].(s V), {s, signs}]
```

I point out htat each matrix `S` in the list `canditates` is a rotation that satisfies `B == S\[Transpose].A.S`, so this problem definitely has more than one solution.

Finally, if really required, you can obtain the Euler angles with

```
EulerAngles /@ canditates
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  Your code is accurate and fast.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I have another question, how to use your algorithm to solve this matrix equation: `A\[Transpose].{{10, 0, 0}, {0, 20, 0}, {0, 0, 25}}.A == {{35/2, (
   5 Sqrt[3])/2, 0}, {(5 Sqrt[3])/2, 25/2, 0}, {0, 0, 25}}`. `A`'s reference answer is EulerMatrix[{Pi/3, 0, 0}].

Comment: Ah good point. Here the input matrices are exact and `Eigensystem` does not normalize the eigenvectors in this case. I added a fix for that.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved in this way, but the warning information will be output:

```
Solve[Thread[
   EulerMatrix[{a, b, c}]\[Transpose].{{10, 0, 0}, {0, 20, 0}, {0, 0, 
       25}}.EulerMatrix[{a, b, c}] == {{35/2, (5 Sqrt[3])/2, 0}, {(
      5 Sqrt[3])/2, 25/2, 0}, {0, 0, 25}}], {a, b, c}] // FullSimplify
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = {{10, 0, 0}, {0, 20, 0}, {0, 0, 25}};
rt = RotationMatrix[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]\[Transpose].{{10, 0, 
      0}, {0, 20, 0}, {0, 0, 
      25}}.RotationMatrix[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}] // FullSimplify;

fg = FindGeometricTransform[r, rt, TransformationClass -> "Rigid"]

EulerAngles[Drop[TransformationMatrix[Last[fg]], -1, -1]]
```