# How to find a solution of this matrix equation quickly

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I need to solve the following matrix equation to find a set of solutions for matrices `A` and `Q` which satisfy the conditions.

```
Q = Array[x, {3, 3}]; 
A = {{a, 0, 1}, {0, a, -1}, {1, -1, a - 1}}; 
sol = FindInstance[
  Transpose[Q] . A . Q == {{b, 0, 0}, {0, c, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} && 
       Transpose[Q] . Q == IdentityMatrix[3] && b > 0 && c > 0, 
     {a, b, c, x[1, 1], x[1, 2], x[1, 3], x[2, 1], x[2, 2], x[2, 3], 
   x[3, 1], 
       x[3, 2], x[3, 3]}]
```

However, the above code takes about `300` seconds to output a set of solutions that meet the requirements. How can I improve this code to get a set of solutions that meet the requirements quickly?

**A set of solutions satisfying conditions:**

```
A={{2, 0, 1}, {0, 2, -1}, {1, -1, 1}};
Q={{-(1/Sqrt[2]), -(1/Sqrt[3]), 1/Sqrt[6]}, 
    {-(1/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[3], -(1/Sqrt[6])}, 
    {0, -(1/Sqrt[3]), -Sqrt[2/3]}};
```

**Updated content & Additional questions:**

```
Q = Array[x, {3, 3}]; 
A = {{1 - a, 1 + a, 0}, {1 + a, 1 - a, 0}, {0, 0, 2}} /. a -> 2; 
FindInstance[
 Thread[Transpose[Q] . A . Q == {{-4, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}], 
 Flatten[Q], Reals]
```

Since `Q` is required to be a real matrix, the above code has been running and cannot return results. How can I quickly get a set of solutions that meet the requirements?

Comment: Once again, you should put more effort in understanding [the answer you obtained](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218283/1871).

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for your guidance, the code in that post is a little bit faster:(it took 115 seconds): `Q = EulerMatrix[{a, b, c}]; 
A = {{f, 0, 1}, {0, f, -1}, {1, -1, f - 1}}; 
sol = FullSimplify[FindInstance[Transpose[Q] . A . Q ==  {{d, 0, 0}, {0, e, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} && 0 <= a <= 2*Pi && 
    0 <= b <= 2*Pi && 
         0 <= c <= 2*Pi && d > 0 && e > 0, {a, b, c, d, e, f}]]`

Comment: `Select[Solve[eqn,Flatten@{Q,a,b,c}],b>0&&c>0/.#&]`

Comment: @chyanog Thank you very much for your code.

Comment: @chyanog I have updated the question, can you quickly solve my additional new problem?

Comment: @Montevideo You can again use `Eigensystem` for your second problem. I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem seems to be more related to finding the eigensystem of `A` than equation solving. For all `a` your matrix is symmetric and real, so using the spectral theorem you know you can diagonalize it using an orthonormal matrix `Q` (which seems to be exactly the problem in your question).

Using `EigenSystem` on `A` we get

```
Eigensystem[A]
```

> ```
> {{-2 + a, a, 1 + a}, {{-1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 1}}}
> ```

The variable `a` is therefore only allowed to take values $-1$, $0$, or $2$, since in your problem you specify that you need one of the eigenvalues to be zero. This corresponds to the `{a,b,c}` triples `{-1,-1,-3}`, `{0,1,2}` and `{2,2,3}`. Of course you can exchange `b` and `c` by flipping rows in `Q`.

The orthonormal eigenvectors, which will span `Q`, are generic for all `a`, and can be determined from `EigenSystem`:

```
Q = #/(Sqrt@Diagonal[#.Transpose[#]]) & @ Eigensystem[A][[2]]
```

> ```
> {{-(1/Sqrt[6]), 1/Sqrt[6], Sqrt[2/3]}, 
>  {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 0}, 
>  {1/Sqrt[3], -(1/Sqrt[3]), 1/Sqrt[3]}}
> ```

So, for `a=-1`, you have the pair

```
A = {{-1, 0, 1}, {0, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -2}};
Q = {{-(1/Sqrt[6]), 1/Sqrt[6], Sqrt[2/3]}, 
     {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 0}, 
     {1/Sqrt[3], -(1/Sqrt[3]), 1/Sqrt[3]}}

Transpose[Q].DiagonalMatrix[{-3, -1, 0}].Q == A
```

for `a=0`

```
A = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}, {1, -1, -1}}
Q = {{-(1/Sqrt[6]), 1/Sqrt[6], Sqrt[2/3]}, 
     {1/Sqrt[3], -(1/Sqrt[3]), 1/Sqrt[3]}, 
     {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 0}}

 Transpose[Q].DiagonalMatrix[{-2, 1, 0}].Q == A
```

and for `a = 2`

```
A = {{2, 0, 1}, {0, 2, -1}, {1, -1, 1}}
Q = {{1/Sqrt[3], -(1/Sqrt[3]), 1/Sqrt[3]}, 
     {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 0}, 
     {-(1/Sqrt[6]), 1/Sqrt[6], Sqrt[2/3]}}

Transpose[Q].DiagonalMatrix[{3, 2, 0}].Q == A
```

**Edit for updated question**

To solve the system in your update, you can again use `Eigensystem`

```
A = {{1 - a, 1 + a, 0}, {1 + a, 1 - a, 0}, {0, 0, 2}} /. a -> 2;
Eigensystem[A]
```

> ```
> {{-4, 2, 2}, {{-1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}}
> ```

```
Q = Normalize /@ {{-1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}};

Transpose[Q].DiagonalMatrix[{-4, 2, 2}].Q == A
```

> ```
> True
> ```

or

```
Q.A.Transpose[Q]
```

> ```
> {{-4, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}
> ```

Comment: Your method is not valid for the following code: `A = {{1, 2, -3}, {-1, 4, -3}, {1, -2, 5}};
Eigensystem[A];
Q = Normalize /@ (Eigensystem[A][[2]]);

Transpose[Q].DiagonalMatrix[{6, 2, 2}].Q == A`.

Comment: Your other examples worked, since they were symmetric matrices, for which the spectral theorem guarantees that a decomposition $Q^TAQ=D$ exists. The matrix in your comment is not symmetric, so it is not even guaranteed to be diagonalizable, but generally it would have the form $P^{-1}AP=D$. Intuitively I would say that it is not possible to find a $Q$ such that $Q^TAQ=D$ provided that $P^{-1}AP=D$ (with $Q\ne P$ and $P$ not orthonormal), since there are uniqueness statements about similarity transformations to the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues, but perhaps I am missing a subtle point.

Comment: Also, for your example in the comment, `FindInstance` also finds no solution: `FindInstance[Thread[Transpose[Q].A.Q == DiagonalMatrix@Eigenvalues[A]],  Flatten[Q], Reals]` yields `{}`

Comment: `DiagonalizableMatrixQ[A]==True`

Comment: Yes, but your matrix is not symmetric, so `Transpose` is not sufficient. For arbitrary (diagonalizable) matrices `A` you can use `Q = Transpose[Normalize /@ (Eigensystem[A][[2]])]; Q.DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues@A].Inverse[Q] == A`. If `A` is *symmetric*, you can replace `Inverse` with `Transpose`, since then `Inverse[Q] === Transpose[Q]`, as `Q` is orthonormal.

Comment: So how can I get an invertible matrix `Q `such that $Q^{-1} A Q=\Lambda$?

Comment: The required `Q` is exactly that computed by the code in my previous comment. You can see that by multiplying your equation with `Q` from the left, and with `Inverse[Q]` from the right.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can diagonalize this way: `Inverse[Q\[Transpose]].A.Q\[Transpose]`.